# Django Raw Query SQL injection display attack

Tags: mysql, sql, django, sql-injection

I am trying to write a website with Django that could display SQL injection for classroom purposes.However when i try to exploit the query nothing is getting returned. I am using a MYSQL database

```
peopledata = people.objects.raw("select * from people where name = \"%s\" "%input
result = list(peopledata)
```

I tried using `"; show tables; --` and `"; --`, in the input field and nothing showed up. Is there a way to display the exploited data?

Comment: Try `" and 1 = 1; --`

Comment: @climbage Thanks. I am getting <RawQuerySet u'select * from people where name ="" and 1=1; --";'>. When i return result i am getting an empty list []

Comment: Oops I'm sorry, I meant to say OR 1=1.  `" or 1 = 1; --`

Comment: Still getting the <RawQuerySet> and not returning the data in the table.

Comment: Could be that `;` isn't allowed in the statement.  Try getting rid of that

Comment: No thats not it. do you know if django is escaping the attack?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31774/discussion-between-climbage-and-user1817081)

Answer (score 0):

Your input should be `any_name OR'x'='x'` or `any_name OR name IS NOT NULL`

The first input would guarantee the clause to be true no matter what the first clause is.

The second query will then return every record in the database, instead of returning the name you searched for.  This is demonstrates a big security risk.  If the data being returned is confidential (id SSN) the user has now received access to data he/she should not be viewing.

Another example would be:

```
any_name; DROP TABLE people; --
```

And:

```
any_name; INSERT INTO people('email','passwd','login_id','full_name') 
        VALUES ('steve@email.com','hello','steve','Steve LastName'); --
```

NOTE:  Apply these queries appropriately to your DB. Using single/double quotes when necessary etc.